# Get more than 2 columns distinct data using group by in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE "spiral_articleinfo" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "url" varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "articletitle" varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    "articleimage" text,
    "articlecontent" text NOT NULL,
    "articlehtml" text NOT NULL,
    "articledate" date,
    "articlecategory" varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    "s_articlecategory" varchar(1000),
    "articlesubcategory" varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    "articledomain" varchar(255),
    "domainrank" integer NOT NULL,
    "articletags" text NOT NULL,
    "articleprice" decimal NOT NULL,
    "contenthash" varchar(255) UNIQUE
);
```

This is the table schema. I want to get distinct articlecategory for every article present group by articledomain. 
I did:

```
select distinct articledomain, articlecategory 
from spiral_articleinfo       
group by articledomain 
order by articledomain;
```

Error coming is:

> ERROR:  column "spiral_articleinfo.articlecategory" must appear in
>   the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

How do I get articlecategories?

When I run this query:

```
select distinct articledomain, articlecategory, articlesubcategory
from spiral_articleinfo;
```

I get:

```
articledomain      | articlecategory | articlesucategory
 androidadvices.com|    Android Apps | Books & Reference
 androidadvices.com|    Android Apps | Business
```

I want the result to be one domain following its articlecategory and articlesubcategory fields. 
Sample Output:

```
articledomain        | articlecategory | articlesucategory
 androidadvices.com  |    Android Apps | Books & Reference, Business
 www.womensweb.in    |             Home|Social Lens, Crime, Law, Safety
 suitcaseofstories.in|         Himachal|Ladakh, People, Street Photography
```

Comment: please add some sample data and the expected output based on that sample data. But it looks like you just need to remove the `group by` part alltogether.

Comment: The data is very huge and I ran this: select distinct articledomain, articlecategory, articlesubcategory from spiral_articleinfo; But this gives me:  androidadvices.com  | Android Apps  | Business
        androidadvices.com  | Android Apps  | Communication
        androidadvices.com  | Android Apps  | Education
        androidadvices.com  | Android Apps  | Entertainment.. But I want all the articledomains to be clubbed together and then the categories fall under in a row.

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar what's the output you're expecting on the basis of output that you posted ?, _I want the result to be one domain following its articlecategory and articlesubcategory fields_ > Show how its should be looks like..

Comment: _But I want all the articledomains to be clubbed together and then the categories fall under in a row_ >  show this as output in your question !

Comment: Apologies for formatting. I have added the sample output. Additionally, I get desired output on sqlite correctly but not on postgresql.

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar try this `select distinct articledomain, articlecategory, string_agg(articlesubcategory,',')
from spiral_articleinfo;`

Comment: Nopes! ERROR:  column "spiral_articleinfo.articledomain" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select distinct articledomain, articlecategory, string_agg(a...

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar `select articledomain, articlecategory, string_agg(articlesubcategory,',') from spiral_articleinfo group by articledomain, articlecategory`

Comment: @NamitaMaharanwar check this out : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d532a/1

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ Post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string_agg()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) function along with `GROUP BY`to achieve the desired output:

with following as an example:

```
create table foow (articledomain text,articlecategory text,articlesucategory text);

insert into foow values ('androidadvices.com','Android Apps','Books & Reference');
insert into foow values ('androidadvices.com','Android Apps','Business');
```

and the select statement should be

```
 select articledomain
       ,articlecategory
       ,string_agg(articlesucategory,',') 
 from foow 
 group by articledomain, articlecategory
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d532a/1)